# Create HTML input field that takes an rgb colour value which changes a textarea background in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, rgb

I have tried searching for hours to solve this issue that I'm facing, I think I understand the principle of how this should work, but I can't seem to be able to find the right way to do it regardless of my effort searching everywhere.

I am working on designing an online text processor (something like Microsoft Word), I have added all I need except that

**I want an input field where an rgb colour value will be entered and the assigned textarea background colour will change. The input has to be within the range of rgb (0 to 255).**

I have tried different things online such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter R"), 10) || 105,
      b = parseInt(prompt("Enter G"), 10) || 105,
      c = parseInt(prompt("Enter B"), 10) || 105;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor= 'rgb(' + a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ')';
</script>
```

But nothing is close to what I need. **NOTE** I played around with this script and many more...

Say I have a textarea:

```
<textarea id="TextArea" placeholder="Please enter your text here.."</textarea>
```

And there is an input field, how can I make the rgb value there change the background colour for the textarea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How would the text look like? Post an example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it finally! it was silly but oh well all mistakes in coding pretty much the silly ones that gets us stuck.

I had to change the prompt so instead of a pop up input window, I wanted a text field where the user can freely enter their rgb values whenever they needed. So I created three textfields and gave each on of them an id, the first I gave r then g then b and assigned each one to a variable document.getElementById("r")

At the end I assigned the result of the three input text to the textarea that I wish to change the bg colour for. As for the validation, it's pretty simple if else statement that ensures the number is equal or below 255 and 0 or above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put your code in a function to `window` call it in `onload` event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function (){
        var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter R"), 10) || 105,
    b = parseInt(prompt("Enter G"), 10) || 105,
    c = parseInt(prompt("Enter B"), 10) || 105;          
    document.querySelector("#TextArea").style.backgroundColor = "#" + a + b + c;    
    }  
</script>
```

You need to do that because browser will execute your javascript code before it terminates to render the HTML.

So we will wrap your code in a function and save it in `onload` to execute it only when browser fisnish the HTML rendering and resources downloads.

To understand `window.onload` take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Comment: thanks for stopping by, I have come across these scripts and this is the same as the one I have tried previously or at least close enough. This will give you a pop up window asking for the R then G then B.

What I'm trying to accomplish is a normal input field where rgb colour can be entered and the background of the textarea will change based on the rgb value. 

**Here is an example from w3chool.**

https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_rgb.asp

Check out the rgb field, whenever you change the value, the colour of the div will change.

Comment: hummm, i was thinking that you want all page background color change. I will update the answer to only change for textarea

Comment: I think you need to put all executable code inside a function and call it in `window.onload` event. i will update the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are setting the background color and not the textarea background color:

see if this example helps you...

```js
  var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter R"), 10) || 105,
      b = parseInt(prompt("Enter G"), 10) || 105,
      c = parseInt(prompt("Enter B"), 10) || 105;
  document.getElementById("TextArea").style.backgroundColor= 'rgb(' + a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ')';
```

```html
<textarea id="TextArea" placeholder="Please enter your text here.."></textarea>`
```

Comment: Thanks man, you see the problem here is that the prompt "enter R" is causing a pop up window. Here is an example of what I'm looking for: 

What I'm trying to accomplish is a normal input field where rgb colour can be entered for example rgb(255, 0, 0) and the background of the textarea will change based on the rgb value. 

**Here is an example from w3chool.**

https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_rgb.asp